# What is this "most reviewed" Matrix fanfic on fanfiction.net?

Tags: story-identification, the-matrix, fan-fiction

[This](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/1618350/1/derp) links to the most reviewed Matrix fanfiction story on fanfiction.net. However, it seems that the story was deleted by a hacker who has left only a single word

> ***"derp"***

I reported it long ago, but the website admin hasn't responded.

**What was this story (and is there another copy available somewhere)?**

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20040903140136/https://www.fanfiction.net/s/1618350/1/

Comment: @Mithrandir I've already checked that. Unfortunately the Wayback Machine doesn't capture more than the first chapter for any story on fanfiction.net because of the site's robots.txt script. You've given me the title and the first chapter. But I'm searching for the full story.

Comment: Some of the reviews have text from the story "*They could be so cute when they weren’t giving you the death glare*" for example, but it's not googleable.

Comment: I'm at a loss why people are casting close-votes. [Shopping questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/499/are-shopping-questions-on-topic) are on-topic when the answer isn't trivially findable (which this certainly isn't), as are Story-ID questions.

Comment: @Valorum: Meh, I blame the "I hate fanfic" group.  It's hard to be certain, but I don't see any other obvious reason to close-vote.  (To be clear: "It's fanfic" is *not* a valid close-vote reason, but some people act like it is...)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The story is "***Third Variable***" by Vampiryyn (AKA Dylan)

It's available online [here](http://moviefanficchains.com/Matrix/Individual%20Fanfic/Third%20Variable%2001.htm). Enjoy...

Comment: Wow! That was fast. Thank You :  )

Comment: @Mr.Riddle - [You're welcome](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wrSsIVqHpM)